# Creating a wifi peer to peer connection programmatically in Java on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, network-programming, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I going to develop desktop application to transfer data using wifi peer to peer connection. What I want to do is display available connections in my app and facilitate user to create connection with selected connection. (The connecting machine also running this application.)
Need some kind of guidance to do this.

Comment: Good. what have you tried?

Comment: still i'm looking for sample to get the list of available wifi connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application, there should be one master connection to which all peers are connected, only by this you can know how many users are connected to your system.